# Using Timer to detect changes

Tags: c#, winforms

UPDATE: I added my code to show the whole process and this is somehow a continuation to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24928472/3839472)

I have 3 items listed in my listview and a `if` statement which states that if my `subitem` is `Inactive` code inside will generate a file. My problem is once the `Inactive` item/s is `Active` again, how will I make my timer to move again?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer2.Enabled = true;
}

    private void running_process()
{

        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses("ITWORKSPC152");
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (flag == false)
            {
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add("Inactive");
                if(i == listView1.Items.Count - 1)
                    flag = true;
            }
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(listView1.Items[i].Text))
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = " ";
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = "Inactive";
                    listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

                if (listView1.Items[i].Text == p.ProcessName)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
                    listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = "Inactive";
                    for (int j = 0; j < listBox1.Items.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (listBox1.Items[j].ToString() == listView1.Items[i].Text)
                        {
                            listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = "Active";
                            listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(66, 181, 33);
                            //m_boolIsDown = false;
                        }

                    }
                }
             }
          }
  }

private void InactiveCheck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + listView1.Items[i].Text + 
                " was inactive at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh':'mm tt") + "\n";
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\pamojica\My Documents\InactiveProgramLogs\" + lbl_date.Text + ".txt", richTextBox1.Text);
            timer3.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            timer3.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    running_process();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InactiveCheck();
    }

    private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i] == null || listView1.Items.Count == 0)
                return;

            var item = listView1.Items[i];

            if (item.SubItems != null && item.SubItems.Count > 1 && item.SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + item.Text + " was inactive at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh':'mm tt") + "\n";
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\pamojica\My Documents\InactiveProgramLogs\" + lbl_date.Text + ".txt", richTextBox1.Text);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Right now, your for belongs to no method, I suppose it's part of the InactivateCheck method?

Comment: Could you improve the title?. It says nothing

Comment: I don't think you need a timer at all - just check this kindof stuff when the items change and btw: your code seems to have a big issue: the last item wins! - I think you really want something like "Exists" or "Any" ...

Comment: XY problem detected: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I'm guessing the timer does something more than check if it's supposed to disable itself and never start again? You either need to different way to check the listView (a second timer or listView.SelectedChanged event) or you need a different mechanism for controlling inactive (drop out of the "Active" method if status is inactive)

Comment: @NatsuDragneel start by telling us what are you trying to achieve with the code you posted. I seems that your are using a wrong approach. Why are you using a timer in the first place?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Sorry bout that can't think of a short title that'll suit the problem

Answer (score 3):

You do not need Timer at all. In your case, the problem is: you want to do something when the value of your item in the listview changes. "event" is the key word here.

Subscribe to an event of your ListView, choose [one here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview_events(v=vs.110).aspx). I think that in that list the event "AfterLabelEdit" is the one you are looking for.

Here is some clues, maybe you should adapt the code to your specific context:

```
listView1.AfterLabelEdit += (o, e) =>
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems == null ||  listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;

    var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

    if (item.SubItems != null && item.SubItems.Count > 1 && item.SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + item.Text + " was inactive at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh':'mm tt") + "\n";
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\pamojica\My Documents\InactiveProgramLogs\" + lbl_date.Text + ".txt", richTextBox1.Text);
    }
};
```

---

Generally speaking, there is almost no simple UI hanlding case where a timer is needed. Just use event.

In a "ListView point of view", using a timer is like:
"I will look around if something changed. If not, I will recheck in a few milliseconds. I will be very busy."

The (better) logic with event is:
"Hey you, controls. All of you: when something changes... keep me posted!"

Comment: I need the timer because thats where it refreshes the listview if any program closes or opens

Comment: Here's what really want to do [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24928472/3839472)

Answer (score 0):

Use `timer3.Stop();` or `timer3.Start();` methods in a ItemSelectionChanged event

```
    private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item == sender)
        {
            if (e.IsSelected) timer3.Start();
            else timer3.Stop();
        }                        
    }
```

Comment: this does not seem to solve his issue (it's the same as setting the `.Enabled` property)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `timer3.Enabled = true;` or `timer3.Enabled =false`
use `timer3.Start();` and `timer3.Stop()`

Stop the Timer in `Tick Event` will do the trick

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer3.Start();

}

private void InactiveCheck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text == "Inactive")
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + listView1.Items[i].Text + " was inactive at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh':'mm tt") + "\n";
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\pamojica\My Documents\InactiveProgramLogs\" + lbl_date.Text + ".txt", richTextBox1.Text);               
        }
        else
        {
            timer3.Start();
        }
    }
}

private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer3.Stop()
    InactiveCheck();
}
```

Comment: this too does not solve the problem at all - plus it's the same answer as the other user gave right before you